# How to get unique rows from the Index column in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a reproducible dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3cafW7J7xSfNmhJQzh3SF9VYms/edit?usp=sharing

I want to delete all the rows which have a same value as the first column of accident index. means that here in data frame if there are 2-3 rows with the first column value same then only 1st row should be kept and others deleted.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
v2<-v1[which(v1$i..Accident_Index==unique(v1$i..Accident_Index))]
```

Please help..thanks

Comment: my bad @Arun its named actually "ï..Acc_Index"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
v2 <- v1[!duplicated(v1$i..Accident_Index), ]
```

To demonstrate this does answer the question:

```
v1 <- data.frame(i..Accident_Index=rep(1:3, each=2), b=letters[1:6])
v1[!duplicated(v1$i..Accident_Index), ]
```

Produces:

```
  i..Accident_Index b
1                 1 a
3                 2 c
5                 3 e
```

Comment: it returns zero rows.. please check the sample data

Comment: @Arun ok, this post was just flagged as a low quality answer by SO

Comment: @Arun its for the column that you name in the argument, which is first column in this case. this perfectly solves it.